# Typescript/React - Multiple types for one prop not working

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have the following types defined. `CurrencyStat` and `ScoreStat` extend `Stat`.

```
export interface Stat {
  value: number;
  change?: number;
}

type Currency = "USD" | "RMB";

export interface CurrencyStat extends Stat {
  currency: Currency;
}

export interface ScoreStat extends Stat {
 outof: number;
}
```

Now I am trying to define a component `StatDisplay`, to display the stat regardless of which Stat type it is. I am getting the following error: `Property 'currency' does not exist on type 'Stat | CurrencyStat'. Property 'currency' does not exist on type 'Stat'.ts(2339)`, even though I am using a union type on the prop `stat`.

I was these `[reading typescript docs][1]` that say "If we have a value that is a union type, we can only access members that are common to all types in the union." This explains why a union type might not work here, but now I am having trouble finding a way to make this work.

I know that it would be possible to delete `CurrencyStat` and just add `currency` as an optional property on `Stat`, but there will be more stat types later on and I would like to have them separate if possible.

```
import { CurrencyStat, ScoreStat, Stat } from "../../../../types/types";
export const StatDisplay = ({
  label,
  stat,
}: {
  label: string;
  stat: Stat | CurrencyStat;
}) => {
  return (
    <div className="flex flex-col items-center">
      <div className="flex items-center">
        <div className="">{stat?.currency}</div>
        <div className="text-2xl font-semibold">{stat.value}</div>
      </div>
      <div className="">{label}</div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CurrencyStat` already implements the `Stat` interface since you're extending it with it.

To fix your issue, all you need to do is change your component function params `stat` variable to be either just `CurrenyStat` or `Stat & Partial<CurrencyStat>`

The `Partial` means that you can pass an object with `Stat` keys but `CurrencyStat` aren't guarenteed.

Here's example:

```
export const StatDisplay = ({
  label,
  stat,
}: {
  label: string;
  stat: Stat & Partial<CurrencyStat>;
}) => { ... }
```

Comment: Thanks! Partials were exactly what I was looking for, since I'll need to specify other Stat types as well. Appreciate the help!